# Example of a Short Exact Sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I know that $A$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. And I have a short exact sequence of the form

$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

is there anything to be said about $A$ ? That is to say, Can I find $A$?

I recall that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is neither projective nor injective as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module so the sequence probably doesn't split. Or does it?

Comment: Indeed, there are two possibilities for what $A$ can be in such a short exact sequence. In one case the sequence splits, in the other it does not. Hint: $A$ has order $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short exact sequence always *could* split. I mean that $0\to M\to M\oplus N\to N\to 0$ is always exact when the maps are the inclusion of $M$ as the first coordinate and the projection onto $N$. But you're right that you can't guarantee this splits via the theorems you alluded to. So the point of a question like this is to see whether $A$ could be anything other than $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$.

So, we know $\mathbb{Z}/2$ injects into $A$, i.e. there's a two-element subgroup $B\subset A$. Since $A/B\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$ as well, $B$ is a two-element subgroup of index 2. That tells us $|A|=4,$ so $A$ could only be $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/4$. And I'll leave it to you to check whether it could be the latter.

Comment: Thanks! but just to make sure I understand this. For $A= \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ this sequence is exact and splits, of course. As for $A = \mathbb{Z}/4 \mathbb{Z}$ I need to check whether this sequence is  exact to begin with? Because I am really not interested in it being split exact; I just need to find $A$ so that my sequence is exact.

Comment: @CarlaB. Remember that $A$ does not usually determine the sequence. You also need to pick the maps.

Comment: Just to provide an example, as I said in the general case we only know the sequence is (split) exact when the maps are $a\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mapsto (a,0)$ and $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mapsto b$. If we changed just the first map to $a\mapsto (a,a)$, which is a perfectly good inclusion of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, the sequence wouldn't even be exact, let alone split!

Comment: What do you mean it would not be exact? That is just a matter of choosing the other map correctly. Any inclusion leads to a short exact sequence. It will indeed even be split in this case. Or did you mean to keep the second map as is?

Comment: Yes, I mean to keep the second map as it is. That's what I meant to communicate by changing "just the first map." Sorry to be unclear.

Comment: @KevinCarlson If I take $ A \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ however, I will not be able to find maps such that the sequence is exact let alone split?  Is that accurate?

Comment: @CarlaB. No. The sequence can easily be exact. You are correct it cannot be split. In fact, if the first map is injective and the second one is surjective, then these maps are uniquely determined and the sequence is exact.

Comment: @CarlaB. $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ has only one subgroup of order 2, so everything is pretty much forced.

Comment: @AndreaMori To be honest, my problem is more complicated than the simple one above, my aim was to find $A= H_2(C_\ast \otimes_\mathbb{Z} C_\ast)$ where $C_\ast$ is a compelex of free abelian groups. and I got the s.e.s above by Kunneth theorem. Now Kunneth theorem also says that said s.e.s must split (not necessarily naturally) ... So, $A$ can't be $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and must hence be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} $right?

Comment: @CarlaB.Certainly $A=(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^2$ with the correct map is the only one that makes the ses split. In the other case $A$ is not even a semidirect product!

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\Bbb Z$-module means abelian group. $A$ needs to have $4$ elements. So either $A=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ or $A=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Can you fit either one in such an exact sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in homology theory but I am aware of the fact that you can actually classify such exact sequences by $\mathrm{Ext}$ groups. Of course, in this case it would be rather foolish thing to use such apparatus in fairly simple case, however, in general setting it might be usefull to check this.

I recommend to look up $\mathrm{Ext}$ in Dummit & Foote Abstract Algebra book

Hope this helps.